# Writing the stdout of subprocess to a file using communicate

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I am using subprocess to run a executable and piping the output of it using communicate. Finally, I write the contents of communicate to a file. The exact code is shown below

```
run = subprocess.Popen(['executable'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = run.communicate()[0]
logfile = open('run.log', 'a')
logfile.write(output)
logfile.close()
```

In the above process, the logfile is written at the end of the run. However, is there a way to write the output to the log as the executable is running?

Comment: This is directly explained in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments): "*stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* specify the executed program’s standard input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively. Valid values are `PIPE`, `DEVNULL`, an existing file descriptor (a positive integer), an existing file object, and `None`."

Answer (score 2):

You mean something like:

```
with open("run.log","a") as f:
      run = subprocess.Popen(['executable'], stdout=f)
```

Comment: use `subprocess.check_call()` to wait for the child process to finish (like in the question). `check_call()` also raises an exception automatically if the subprocess returns a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Thanks @padraic. While the above works, the terminal gets free from the executable. Is there a way for the `subprocess` to retain the executable in the terminal until the run is over?

Comment: @Deepak: just replace `Popen` with `check_call` as I've suggested. The parameters are the same.

Comment: As `Popen` returns after it has started the process, wont it leave the `with` block causing `f` to be left as a closed file?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to this:

```
logfile = ('run.log', 'w')
run = subprocess.Popen(['executable'], stdout = logfile)
run.wait()
logfile.close()
```

The first line creates the `run.log` for writing and `stdout` writes directly to the logfile as the executable is running. The `run.wait()` waits for the executable to complete and then the log file is closed.